# Transcription of letter from ca. 1890 in Kurrent - difficult words

Tags: meaning-in-context, kurrent

I am currently transcribing a letter from about 1890 [image: Excerpt of relevant part of the letter]from the Norwegian Professor of Philosophy Marcus Jacob Monrad to an unnamed Italian Professor. However, I have problems with deciphering three words, below marked with XXX. Any suggestions would be most welcome:

Ich
habe seitdem Nichts von Ihm
erfahrt bis vor Kurzen, da ich
einen
— leider vom Manicomio [i.e. the asylum] in Rom
XXX — Brief von ihm erhielt.
Er spricht darin von literarischen
und wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten,
besonders von mehreren jour-
nalistischen Unternehmungen;
klagt übrigens über seine XXX,
und bittet mich nicht undeutlich
um einiger Hülfe.  Nun
kann man eigentlich nicht
wissen, was daran wahr — oder
XXX [eine???] Phantasie eines Geistes-
kranken ist, und so möchte ich
Sie fragen, ob Sie ihn noch kennen
und wissen, was aus ihm gewor-
den ist, oder etwas von seiner
jetzigen Lage.

Comment: The first word is "datiert". The third could be "alleine" or "alles".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it will not be useful for other users. It's a service request.

Comment: @user unknown: Please see https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1656/general-question-re-deciphering-transcription-of-handwritten-texts/1657#1657

Comment: Coorection: The first word is "datierten".

Comment: @Paul Frost: Yes, thank you. Your initial input helped me to identify "datierten". Any suggestions re the second problem?

Comment: @Helge No. The third letter should be an "l" and the last letter an "h" (which would not fit after an "l") or possibly an "f".

Comment: @PaulFrost The second word might be "Noth". The "l" is rather a "t" missing the bar, a very common omission (see the following lines: three "t"s in "bittet" and none is properly crossed). The resulting sentence "klagt über seine Noth und bittet um Hülfe" makes good sense.

Comment: @marquinho You are right! I suggest that you write an official answer because the "hard part" was deciphered by you.

Comment: @PaulFrost That is very nice of you! Will do.

Answer (score 5):

The words (in context) are:

1. "einen vom Manicomio in Rom **datierten** Brief" (possibly written in the old orthography "datirten")
2. "klagt übrigens über seine **Noth**, und bittet [...] um *einige* Hülfe.": he laments his difficult situation and begs for help.
   For help deciphering this, compare the "N" in the word "Nun"; the "l"-looking letter is actually an uncrossed "t" – this omission was very common in Kurrent writing - just as in the word "bittet" in the next line.
   (Note that it's "einige" not "einiger", though Monrad seems to have written "einiges" at first.)
3. Paleographically and semantically speaking, this could be either **allein** or **alles**: "was daran wahr — oder **allein** Phantasie... ist".

Credit to Paul Frost for deciphering no. 1 and 3.